# how do I access controller that is in sub directory of "application/controllers" when $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

my codeigniter application config:

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

so I can access my application like this : `index.php?c=index&m=about`

but I have a controller in "application/controllers/setting/" directory , named user.php

if mod_rewrite is enabled , i can access like : 
`index.php/setting/user/someMethod`

but How do I access it like this : 
`index.php?c=setting/user&m=someMethod`
the result is **404 Not Found**

log file says:

`ERROR - 2011-08-11 08:03:07 --> 404 Page Not Found --> settinguser`

**EDIT**

Answer:

`index.php?d=setting&c=user&m=someMethod`

Comment: what does the CI log say when you try to access a page via the above URL?

Comment: @BigFatBaby: `ERROR - 2011-08-11 08:03:07 --> 404 Page Not Found --> settinguser`  two name were merged together.

Comment: well that slash has to be incorrect there if you are accessing it without mod_rewrite.  but what exactly the correct key not sure. but has to be something like &t=user  (not sure about t or what else)

Comment: @Dreadedsemicolon: you inspired me,problem solved. thansk very much.

Comment: Aw, you already had the answer. LOL ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access them like this

```
index.php?d=setting&c=user&m=someMethod
```

You need the directory trigger if you have a sub directory.
It's in your `config.php` file but it has the `experimental` comment.

```
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd'; // experimental not currently in use
```

Comment: so what if i have multi-directories like "application/controllers/setting/test/user.php"

Comment: codeigniter doesn't support it, only allows one level of subdirectory for organizing controllers, http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#subfolders.